# What are the ways to calculate polarity of a sentence when using supervised learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, logistic-regression

I want to calculate the polarity of the sentence like `VADER` or `TextBlob` does without using these libraries.

I have used Logistic Regression to train the model and used `predict_proba()`.

Does this give me the polarity of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict_proba()` : gives you a probability score , if your case is a binary classification case , then you can set a threshold say

```
if (p > 0.5) then +ve Polarity / -Ve polarity
```

or

You can find the best optimal threshold (`say p >0.7 , then +ve/-eve polarity`)based on the data , But that's a different case altogether.
For calculating the best threshold curve , see `F1 Score` or `ROC`

Comment: I want the polarity of a phrase, something like {'positive': 0.4, 'negative': 0.6}. My question is, does predict_proba() give me that?

Comment: No , predict_proba() gives you a probability , score , its upto you to define what that score means .Think this way , For a particular subject in high school, you get a score say 75 out of 100 , How will you define if you have a distinction or not? ,That's  ,you need to define a threshold first .And based on that you can define if a score should be mapped to +/- ve polarity